# twitter login issue due to twitter kit with fabric.with() first?

Tags: android, twitter

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start Twitter Kit with Fabric.with() first
at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterCore.checkInitialized(TwitterCore.java:156)
at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterCore.getInstance(TwitterCore.java:74)
at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient.<init>(TwitterAuthClient.java:71)
```

Why this error is thrown?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the SDK with:

```
TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(YOUR_TWITTER_API_KEY, YOUR_TWITTER_API_SECRET);
Fabric.with(this, new TwitterCore(authConfig));
```

where `this` refers to a `Context` and replacing your API key and secret with the one you get from Twitter's developer website.